# Find angle of point on circle

Tags: java, android, math, trigonometry

Imagine I have drawn a circle with center coordinates (cx,cy) on the screen and a random point (A) is selected on the circle.

[image: trigonometric circle]

By having the the coordinates of point A, I need to find the angle of (a).

Update:

I have tried using the following formula:

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(((x - cx) / radius).toDouble()))
```

which is actually the reverse of (the circle is created by feeding angles to this one):

```
x = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle.toDouble())) + cx
y = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle.toDouble())) + cy
```

But since the y coordinate is not present in the formula the answer could be wrong.

Comment: see `java.lang.Math` package documentation. did you try to ^F `angle`?

Comment: In my geometry classes, zero degrees is on the east side of the circle

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you know the cartesian coordinates of the point A(x,y), then you can find the angle theta by converting it into polar coordinates as below:

```
double theta = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y - cy, x - cx));
```

This formula works if your X axis is in 0 degrees, otherwise you need to consider the offset.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here is that this formula can not differentiate between quadrants correctly. This formula always return an angle from 0 to 180.

Comment: You can figure out the angle using CAST rule, eg. if both x and y are positive the angle is same, and if both x and y are negative the angle is theta+180

Comment: @HamedMomeni so did you check the `Math` package documentation? *"This method computes the phase theta by computing an arc tangent of y/x in the range of -pi to pi"*

Comment: @pskink you are correct. `System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(2,2)));` prints 45 whereas `System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(-2,-2)));` prints -135.

Answer (score 4):

I think the method you are looking for i Math.atan2 which computes the angle to an x and y cordinate. I have now modified the code to adjust for putting 0 degrees downwards. I have also flipped the y-axis to put 0, 0 cordinate in the upper left corner (screen coordinates), and adjusted degrees above 180 to be reported as negative degrees:

```
public double theta(int cx, int cy, int x, int y)
{
    double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(cy - y, x - cx)) + 90;
    return angle <= 180? angle: angle - 360;
}
```

A small test to verify some angles...

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    assertThat(theta(50, 50, 60, 50), is(90.0));
    assertThat(theta(50, 50, 50, 60), is(0.0));
    assertThat(theta(50, 50, 40, 50), is(-90.0));
    assertThat(theta(50, 50, 50, 40), is(180.0));
}
```

Comment: right answer but... the direction is reversed and the starting point is offset by pi / 2 - so i dont think the OP accepts it as he wants the fish, not the fishing rod

Answer (score 3):

You can find the tangent angles and add to 90 or substruct from 270 that angle and find the result, I believe. I design the code like your drawing. You can make it more generic, I guess. 
You have 4 area:

1. 0 degree to 90 degree
2. 90 degree to 180 degree
3. 90 degree to -90(270) degree
4. -90(270) degree to 0(360) degree

Code:

```
public static double findAngle(double x,  double y,
                               double cx, double cy, double radius){
    double beta, alfa;

    double distanceX = Math.abs(Math.abs(x) - Math.abs(cx));
    double distanceY = Math.abs(Math.abs(y) - Math.abs(cy));

    // check the point is on the circle or not
    // with euchlid
    if (radius != Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (x >= cx && y <= cy) {
        // find tangent
        beta = Math.atan(distanceY / distanceX);
        alfa = 90 - beta;
        return alfa;
    }
    // 90-180 -> second area
    else if (x >= cx && y >= cy) {
        beta = Math.atan(distanceY / distanceX);
        alfa = 90 + beta;
        return alfa;
    }
    // 180 - -90 -> third area
    else if (x <= cx && y >= cy) {
        beta = Math.atan(distanceY / distanceX);
        alfa = 270 - beta;
        return alfa;
    }
    // -90 - 0 -> forth area
    else if (x <= cx && y <= cy) {
        beta = Math.atan(distanceY / distanceX);
        alfa = 270 + beta;
        if (alfa == 360) {
            alfa = 0;
        }
        return alfa;    
    } 
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main catch with `Atan2` is the center point. If your center is offset `(Cx, Cy)` and not at the origin and you want to find the arc angle between `(X1, Y1)` and `(X2, Y2)` then I would suggest this approach:

```
double startAngle = Math.Atan2(Y1-Cy, X1-Cx);
double endAngle = Math.Atan2(Y2-Cy, X2-Cx);
double ArcAngle = endangle - startAngle;
```